# How to change datatype after parsing?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parsing

Here is my full working code.

When imported into Excel the data is imported as text.

How do I change the data type?

```
​​from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://www.cbr.ru/hd_base/dv/?P1=4")
driver.find_element_by_id('UniDbQuery_FromDate').clear()
driver.find_element_by_id('UniDbQuery_FromDate').send_keys('13.01.2013')
driver.find_element_by_id('UniDbQuery_ToDate').clear()
driver.find_element_by_id('UniDbQuery_ToDate').send_keys('12.12.2017')
driver.find_element_by_id("UniDbQuery_searchbutton").click()
z=driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup=BeautifulSoup(z)
x=[]
for tag in soup.tbody.findAll('td'):
    x.append(tag.text) 
y=x[1::2]
d=pd.Series(y)
```

Comment: If this is your full code, you're missing the pandas import

Comment: But this does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.astype` method for series:

```
d = d.astype(int)
```

or whatever datatype you're trying to convert to in place of `int`. Note that this will give you an error if there's anything in your series that it can't convert - you may need to drop null values or strip whitespace first if that happens.